# Parent-Child relations in angular 4

Tags: angular

**This is my db.json after submit i want**

```
{
    "id": 0,
    "code": "string",
    "name": "string",
    "isActive": true,
    "questionerdetails":[
        {
            "id":0,
            "questiondetail": "string",
            "isActive": true
        }
    ]
}
```

**This is my method in questioner.component.ts**

```
formSubmits() {
    this.validate = true;
    this.preProcessConfigurations();
    let questioner = this.questionerForm.value;
    let question = this.questions;

    this.allquestionare.forEach(obj => {

      question.push({ 'questiondetail': '' })
    })

    console.log(questioner);
    this.questionareService.getAllQuestioner()
      .subscribe(questionerss => {

        this.questionareService.createQuestioner(questioner)
          .subscribe(successCode => {
            this.statuscode = successCode;
            this.questionerForm.reset();
            alert("Success");

          },
          errorCode => this.statuscode = errorCode
          );
      });

  }
```

please help--
i got stuck in method form submits, to push the child class questionerdetails into parent class

Comment: I am not sure whether I understand your question. But if you need to create a model property then use Array<QuestionerDetails>

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Have you tried anything so far? StackOverflow isn't a free code-writing service, and expects you to try to solve your own problem first. Please update your question to show what you have already tried, showing the specific problem you are facing in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the similar requirement. I have used the approach like, I have created two models. In your situation say `Questionnaire` and `QuestionnaireDetails`. Into `Questionnaire` there will be the array of  `QuestionnaireDetails`. You can use constructor or setter/getters to set/get data.

Check example given below,

**Questionnaire Model**

```
export class Questionnaire {

    private id: number;
    private code: string;
    private name: string;
    private isActive;
    private questionerdetails: QuestionnaireDetails[];

    constructor(){
    }
}
```

**QuestionnaireDetails Model**

```
export class QuestionnaireDetails {

    private id: number;
    private questionnairedetail: string;
    private isActive;

    constructor(){
   }
}
```